# How to display message based on cart total in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to display a message in a custom page template based on the cart total using a function but it not displaying my message.

Please see function below:

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_order, 'woocommerce_order_subtotal' );
function woocommerce_order_subtotal(){ 

    $sub = WC()->cart->total();

    // if for the subtotal:

    if ($sub > 100)) {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? Specifically the Woocommerce stuff and the HTML? Also, what are you expecting and what is the error?

Comment: Can you share the other code blocks of your page template?

Comment: Hi guys,apologies for the delay, i have edited the function to display everything i am trying to use to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You should get the subtotal when calling the cart not the total

```
   add_shortcode( 'custom_order, 'woocommerce_order_subtotal' );
    function woocommerce_order_subtotal(){ 

        $sub = WC()->cart->total(); //this is wrong here you gettin total not subtotal
         $sub = WC()->cart->subtotal
         //Or this following         
         $sub = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()

        // if for the subtotal:

        if ($sub > 100)) {
            echo "Hello world!";
    }
   }
```